# getView on fragment returning null when called from different fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have an activity that contains two fragments. One of the fragments, mainFragment, is the size of the whole screen. There is another fragment, summaryFrag, that is contained in a view inside of mainFragment. I am trying to update text on summaryFrag based on an action that happens in mainFragment.

Goal: When a button is pressed in mainFragment, set the text of a TextView in summaryFrag to something.

I tried to do this by getting the TextView from inside of mainFragment by using

`TextView textView = (TextView) summary.getView().findViewById(R.id.prev_guess_txt);`

but I get a null pointer exception error

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.damia.bullseyev3, PID: 6049
              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
                  at com.example.damia.bullseyev3.fragments.mainFragment.updatePreviousGuesses(mainFragment.java:83)
                  at com.example.damia.bullseyev3.fragments.mainFragment$1.onClick(mainFragment.java:68)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22260)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

---

**mainFragment.java**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    scrollView = (ScrollView) v.findViewById(R.id.scroll);
    ll = (LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);


    submitBtn = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.submit_guess_btn);

    submitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            updatePreviousGuesses();
        }
    });

    return v;
}

public void updatePreviousGuesses(){
    //TODO add method to check if guess is valid first before updating the scrollview
    FrameLayout holder = new FrameLayout(getActivity());
    holder.setId(R.id.holder);

    summaryFrag summary = summaryFrag.newInstance("","");
    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.holder, summary).commit();

    TextView textView = (TextView) summary.getView().findViewById(R.id.prev_guess_txt);
    textView.setText("test");

    ll.addView(holder, 0);
}
```

---

**summaryFrag.java**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.summary, container, false);

    return v;
}
}
```

(summaryFrag has nothing changed from the default generated fragment code at the moment)

---

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    mainFragment mainfrag = (mainFragment)fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);

    if(mainfrag == null){
        mainfrag = mainFragment.newInstance("","");
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, mainfrag).commit();
    }
}
}
```

---

I have read a few solutions about this, and I know it is due to the fragment lifestyle and everything, but I still have tried to fix it on my own and have not been successful. I've tried moving some things to onViewCreated instead but I don't know how it works well enough to know what SHOULD be moved there and what shouldn't.

I'm new to callbacks and everything so if your solution includes them could you please explain it to a beginner a bit :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Better use setarguments & getarguments when you are trying to interact between fragments